# Knockout- How to get the value from a select and pass it to an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, knockout.js

http://jsfiddle.net/smihit_123/kopp8h53/

```
 self.selectedCity.subscribe(function () {
        alert("this is percentage" + this.percentBonus);
    })
```

How to get the value of the observable property in knockout? As an example in jsfiddle, how can i get the value of percentBonus and use it when the combo box is changed.

Also how can i make the combo box of city change when i change the value of state.

In practical scenario there will be states and the cities will change depending on the state selected. I will get the list of cities from the server by making an ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a select you need observable not observable array.

```
self.selectedCity = ko.observable();
self.selectedCity.subscribe(function () {
    alert("this is percentage" + self.percentBonus());
})
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raheelshan/kopp8h53/3/)

For a combo box you can call change event

```
<select id="stateSelect" style="background-color:#69bed2; width:50px;" data-placeholder="..." 
data-bind="
        options: stateValue, 
        selectedOptions: selectedStates,
        event:{change:$root.ChangeCity}"
name="state" class="chosen-select" tabindex="1"></select>
```

And in viewmodel

```
self.cityValue = ko.observableArray();
self.ChangeCity = function(state){
    $.ajax({
        data: {state : state}
        .
        .
        .
        success : function(array){
            self.cityValue(array)
        }

    })
}
```